# Exception by using a surrogate in protobuf-net

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I have a DataCollection class that has a nested List in it. I'm trying to use a Surrogate class for it where I'm shiming the List> into a List and the surrogating the Dto class itself.

I'm creating a RuntimeTypeModel

```
_model = TypeModel.Create();
_model.Add(typeof(DataCollection), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(DataCollectionSurrogate));
_model.Compile();`
```

If I compile the model I get the following exception.

`System.ArgumentExceptionRepeated data (a list, collection, etc) has inbuilt behaviour and cannot use a surrogate`

What exactly is it conveying here? That there are some methods in the class itself? That doesn't seem to matter in other cases.
I don't understand the message it's supposed to convey.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Does your `DataCollection` inherit from `List` or some other collection class? Look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614968/exception-serializing-custom-collection

Comment: It does inherit from IEnumerable and I can relate to the point MArc is making in the other thread. But isn't a surrogate supposed to address just this issue?

Comment: @tzachs your comment was actually the right answer. After re-factoring I now can use the surrogate just fine. If you put it in an answer I can mark it as the solution

Comment: Happy that it works for you now, I think it's actually best to mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, collections of items are very different to items, in many of the internals. The library allows you to use surrogates for the items, but does **not** allow you to use surrogates for anything that it is treating as a list/collection... which for the purposes of protobuf-net means:

- satisfies the `foreach` requirements (usually, but not necessarily, by implementing `IEnumerable[<T>]`
- has a suitable `Add(T)` method for appending items
- some `T` can be identified (or explicitly specified) that satisfies the above
- is not explicitly marked as `SkipListHandling`

If your type shouldn't behave like a list, then set `SkipListHandling` on the `[ProtoContract]`... but: *don't expect it to behave like a list* if you do so. It will be treated as an item only.